# How to ignore an interceptor for a particular route in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have set a controller level interceptor `@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)`.
Now I want one of the controller routes to ignore that interceptor, is there any way to achieve that in nest.js?

For this particular case I want to be able to disable `CacheInterceptor` for one of the routes.

```
@Controller()
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
export class AppController {
  @Get('route1')
  route1() {
    return ...;
  }

  @Get('route2')
  route2() {
    return ...;
  }
  @Get('route3')
  route3() {
    return ...;
  }
  @Get('route4')
  route4() {
    return ...; // do not want to cache this route
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1050#issuecomment-418639184), there is [no additional exclude decorator](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1050#issuecomment-419073908) but instead you can just extend the `CacheInterceptor` and provide the excluded routes.

```
@Injectable()
class HttpCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
  trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const isGetRequest = this.httpServer.getRequestMethod(request) === 'GET';
    const excludePaths = ['path1', 'path2'];
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (
      !isGetRequest ||
      (isGetRequest && excludePaths.includes(this.httpServer.getRequestUrl))
    ) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.httpServer.getRequestUrl(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was searching in github issues but didn't found that one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW can you set a specific ttl for each path using `custom/extended` interceptor? Say I want `route1` and `route2` have `ttl` 5 hours, `route3` and `route4` 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

```
  const IgnoredPropertyName = Symbol('IgnoredPropertyName')
  
  export function CustomInterceptorIgnore() {
    return function(target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
      descriptor.value[IgnoredPropertyName] = true
    };
  }
  
  
  @Injectable()
  export class CustomInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor() {}
  
    async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {
      const request: ExtendedUserRequest = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
      const isIgnored = context.getHandler()[IgnoredPropertyName]
      if (isIgnored) {
        return next.handle()
      }
    }
  }
  
  @Patch('route')
  @CustomInterceptorIgnore()
  async someHandle () {
  
  }
```

Comment: For every handler(function) adds special property. And then if in interceptor this property was found  interceptor will not work for this handler.

Comment: This may be a valid example, but unfortunately I couldn't get this approach to work.